# How to create automated blog post on elgg

Tags: elgg

Each time a have a new version of my product i want automaticaly create an automated blog post with the file or link to new version on elgg.

Is there any way to that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want it integrated:

- You can create a plugin that will use cron mechanism in Elgg to check some external source and create blog entity in code if needed
- You can expose this ability to external service to send request to Elgg installation and make the blog entry using core WebServices mechanism described here http://learn.elgg.org/en/stable/guides/web-services.html